# Is the number of orbits of the automorphism group of infinite field with a finite characteristic acting of the field is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, model-theory

I am trying to solve some statement in Model theory. 
And if i can show that given an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$ with a finite character, then the number of orbits of $Aut(\mathbb{F})$ acting on $\mathbb{F}^n$ is finite, it will solve my problem. so any help will be appreciated!

Also if there is a canonic form for such a group it will help to check it by myself if you can tell me what it is...

> I meant to write infinite number of orbits not finite.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Finite characteristic?

Comment: Yes, 'character' here is unusual. Do you mean 'characteristic' - that is, the field contains some $\mathbb F_p$ for some prime $p$?

Comment: actually i just realised i have made a mistake. i need the number of orbits of the operation of $Aut(\mathbb{F})$  on $\mathbb{F}^n$ to be finite for all $n<\omega$ i will edit the question

Comment: yes characteristic, A mistake in translation..

Comment: @sha As originally stated, if $\Bbb F$ is the field of fractions for a polynomial ring over a finite field and infinitely many indeterminates, you can show that $\Bbb F$ is an infinite field of finite characteristic with infinitely many automorphisms.

Comment: and there is a way i can tell if the number of orbits are finite?

Comment: @sha Not sure, you made that correction literally seconds before I was about to post that comment as a solution, so I've had no time to think about it. I'll think about it.

Comment: Given $\mathbb F=\mathbb F_p(x,y)$ for indeterminates $x,y$, then there is an automorphism equal to the identity on $\mathbb F_p$ and $x$,  and sending $y\mapsto xy$. Then the orbit of $y$ is infinite.

Comment: @sha You're having $Aut(F)$ act like this?  $\phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=(\phi(x_1),\ldots,\phi(x_n))$?

Comment: @rschwieb yes like that

Comment: Actually, letting $k$ be any infinite field of finite characteristic, then $F=k(x)$ has $x$ with orbits $x+a$ for any $a\in k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm sorry but my knowledge in filed theory is not that good. does all infinite field of finite characteristics are of that form? maybe for a finitely many  indeterminates? and your statement will still hold?

Comment: Oh, wait, I misread the fixed question, given your original question. I assumed you wanted the size of all orbits to be finite (since that is "like" $Aut(F)$ being finite, which was your original question.) The number of orbits is an entirely different question.

Comment: sorry for causing confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an infinite structure $M$, we say that $\text{Aut}(M)$ is *oligomorphic* if the action of $\text{Aut}(M)$ on $M^n$ has finitely many orbits for all $n\in \omega$.

Now if $\text{Aut}(M)$ is oligomorphic, then there are only finitely many first-order $n$-types relative to $T = \text{Th}(M)$ for all $n\in \omega$, and as a consequence $T$ is countably categorical and there are only finitely formulas in $n$ free variables up to equivalence modulo $T$. This is what's called the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem.

I claim that *no* infinite field $F$ has a countably categorical theory $T$. Indeed, since $F$ is infinite, we can find an elementary extension $F'$ of $F$ containing an element $a$ which is transcendental over $F$ (use Löwenheim-Skolem, or write down the type $\{p(x) \neq 0\mid p\in F[x]\}$ and use compactness). Then $F'$ contains distinct elements $\{a^n\mid n\in \omega\}$, and we have infinitely many formulas in two free variables, $\{y = x^n\mid n\in\omega\}$, which are pairwise inequivalent modulo $T$ (since they have different realizations in $F'$, witnessed by the pairs $(a,a^n)$).

So no field satisfies the condition in your question, and the characteristic is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! that was really helpful.

Comment: i actually meant to write that the number of orbits are infinite, didn't notice until now

Comment: Why $Aut(M)$ being oligomorphic implies that there are finitely many $n$-types relative to $Th(M)$ ?

Comment: @BinyaminRiahi If there is an automorphism mapping an $n$-tuple $a$ to an $n$-tuple $b$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same type. So oligomorphic automorphism group immediately implies that there are only finitely many $n$-types realized in $M$ for all $n$. Now you can argue that each of these $n$-types must be isolated by a single formula, and the theory of $M$ says that every $n$-tuple must satisfy one of those isolating formulas, so these are the only types consistent with the theory of $M$.

Comment: @BinyaminRiahi for more details, you can look up a proof of the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem, e.g. Theorem 7.3.1 in *Model Theory* by Hodges (6.3.1 in *A Shorter Model Thoery*). The claim I made is the implication (c) implies (e) in Hodges's statement. Not that Hodges considers only countable structures here, but countability is not used in the proof of this implication.

Comment: Nice ! Actually my problem wasnt about the types that $M$ realizes, but I wasnt able to understand why are there only a finite number of types that $M$ doesnt realize. In fact Hodges shows that there are 0 of them. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

This is usually not true (in fact, off the top of my head, I don't know how to construct any example where it is true).  For instance, if $\mathbb{F}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, then every automorphism maps $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ to itself for each $n$, so $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}\setminus\bigcup_{d\mid n, d<n}\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is a union of orbits for each $n$.  This set is nonempty for every $n$, so there are infinitely many orbits.  For another example, every automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ preserves the degree of rational functions, so there are infinitely many orbits (at least one for each degree).

Comment: I, I misread the question, based on the erroneous first version of the question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, while reading the other answer i realised that i wrote finite number of orbits instead of infinite. So i couldn't make sense of the answer. and now i do